# A question about degree of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity $1 \in R$, let $R[x]$ be the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $R$, and let the polynomial $f(x)$ be invertible in $R[x]$. If $R$ is an integral domain, show that $\text{deg}(f(x))=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition if $f(x)$ is invertible, then there exists a polynomial $g(x)$ such that

> $f(x)g(x)=1$.

Now the degree of the polynomial $1$ is $0$. What can you conclude about the degree of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: I don't want to give away too much, but make sure to use the fact that R is an integral domain and think about the above hint.

Comment: Excellent comment by @clem. Make sure you understand why the hypothesis $R$ is an integral domain is needed in the proof.

Comment: That's my point, I don't understand why we need the condition that $R$ is an integral domain.

Comment: @user236626: what can you conclude about the degree of $f$ from the above equation?

Comment: $deg f(x)+deg g(x)=0$

Comment: @user236626: As a (counter)example you might want to think about
$R=\mathbb{Z_4}$ and $f(x)=(2x^2+1)$. Note that $R$ is not an integral domain, and that $f$ is invertible. This example might help you understand why we need $R$ to be an integral domain.

Comment: @user236626: deg$f$ + deg$g$= $0$ would need the hypothesis. See the example above.

Comment: what is the hypothesis to make $deg f(x)+deg g(x)=0$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12608/discussion-between-user236626-and-voldemort)

Comment: @user236626: The highest degree term in the product $fg$ comes by multiplying the highest degree term in $f$ with the highest degree term in $g$. This term is non zero as $R$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 0):

Go for a contradiction.  Assume that $\deg(f)\geq 1$  Write out the polynomial, which has nonzero leading coefficient $a_n$ 
$$f(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$$

Write the inverse function with nonzero lead coefficient

$$f^{-1}(x)=b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+b_1x+b_0$$

$f(x)f^{-1}(x)$ has the lead term $a_nb_mx^{n+m}$ where $\deg(f(x)f^{-1}(x))= n+m\geq1$.  because $a_nb_m\neq0$ since we are in an integral domain.  Also, $f(x)f^{-1}(x)=1$, which has degree 0.  Contradication.  Therefore, $\deg(f)=0$ if $f$ has an inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)$ be the inverse of $f(x)$. Then $f(x)g(x) = 1$.

In an integral domain we have

$deg(f(x)g(x)) = deg(f(x)) + deg(g(x))$.

This can be seen straight from the definition of the degree: the leading coefficien of $f(x)g(x)$ is the product of the leading coefficents of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ so it's nonzero (because $R$ is integral domain). Hence

$deg(f(x)g(x)) \geq deg(f(x)) + deg(g(x))$.

Coefficients of larger powers are zero so we have equality:

$deg(f(x)g(x)) = deg(f(x)) + deg(g(x))$.

Now $deg(f(x)) + deg(g(x)) = deg(1) = 0$ and since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both invertible they can't be the zero polynomial. Hence it must be that both have degree $0$.